# laravel 5.4 modify data before validation in request

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4

I have my custom Request, which extends the Backpack CrudController.

Now I would like to override the prepareForValidation of the ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait since it looks like the right place to modify my incoming data, but I can't figure out how ...

So my first question is, can I override this method? Its protected ...

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
```

And my second question, **how can I modify my input on the Request or FormRreuqest objects?**

Here is my RequestClass

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Config;

class DonationsRequest extends \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Requests\CrudRequest
{


    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return \Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'dob' => 'required|date',
            'newsletter' => 'required|boolean',
            'country' => 'sometimes|required|in:'.implode(',', Config::get('validation.countries')),
            'street' => 'sometimes|required|string|max:255',
            'zip' => 'sometimes|required|string|between:4,5',
            'city' => 'sometimes|required|string|between:4,255',
            'amount' => 'required|numeric|between:1,'.Config::get('donations.max'),
            'type' => 'required|in:oo,monthly',
            'provider' => 'sometimes|string|nullable',
            'product_id' => 'sometimes|exists:products,id|nullable',
            'campaign_id' => 'required|exists:campaigns,id',
            'status' => 'sometimes|required|in:pending,canceled,success,error',
            'profile' => 'sometimes|string|regex:/^profile[0-9]+$/|nullable',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    private function prepareForValidation()
    {

        dd('getValidatorInstance custom');

        $this->sanitizeInput();

        return parent::getValidatorInstance();
    }

    private function sanitizeInput()
    {

        dd('sanitizeInput custom');

        $data = $this->all();

        dd($data);

        // overwrite the newsletter field value to match boolean validation
        $data['newsletter'] = ($data['newsletter'] == 'true' || $data['newsletter'] == '1' || $data['newsletter'] == true) ? true : false;

        return $data;
    }

    private function validate() {
        dd('validate');
    }
}
```

**As you can see**, I first tried to override the getValidatorInstance method, since this looked like the common aproach to this, but it is not executed (so not overridden - protected?).

Comment: I'm unable to test at the moment, but is this perhaps just a typo? `private function prepareForValidation()`, try changing this to public.

Comment: nope, doesn't make a difference ... can't override the method :/ thx!

Comment: It doesn't matter if `prepareForValidation()` is protected, this is the method you're supposed to override to perform these types of tasks. Inside this method, call `$this->replace()` to replace your inputs with the sanitized variants.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I found out where the error was. I did split the Frontend Request and the Backend Request Call. Since I was working on the Backend Request the Frontend Request was not overwriting anything ... so it was my bad, no bug there, sry for the waste of time, but a big thanks to the community!

Answer (score 15):

Although I didn't tried but it seems it should work you can override **`validationData`** from [**`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L110-L113) class like.

```
/**
 * Get data to be validated from the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function validationData()
{
    $all = parent::validationData();
    //e.g you have a field which may be json string or array
    if (is_string($playerIDs = array_get($all, 'player_id')))
        $playerIDs = json_decode($playerIDs, true);

    $all['player_id'] = $playerIDs
    return $all;
}
```

or you can override **`all`** method in [**`Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput`**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L119-L122) trait

```
/**
 * Get all of the input and files for the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function all()
{
    $all = parent::all();
    //then do your operation
    if (is_string($playerIDs = array_get($all, 'player_id')))
        $playerIDs = json_decode($playerIDs, true);

    $all['player_id'] = $playerIDs
    return $all;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of them, but it doesn't accept the overrides. Do I have to make something special to make this work? Mention the trait or class somehow?

Comment: @ThomasVenturini I have updated my answer please check the history & if your aren't successful then please update your question let us know what you did

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.7. What's the equivalent for this?

Comment: @ggderas Works in 5.7

Answer (score 4):

Could you modify the request?

```
$request->merge(['field' => 'new value']);
```

Comment: And where would I do so? The problem, as described, is that I can't find the method to override. But thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I am sure,this can help in modifying The input, it worked for me.[laravel 5.4]

place this

```
$input['url'] = $url;
$this->replace($input);
dd($input);
```

in listFormRequest. (use `$all` instead of `$input`, if you follow above used answer).

This only changes input,which is available even in controller. You still need to find a way to insert it into DB, or do something else to use modified input for using it in blade.

Comment: This may be the answer to Thomas Venturini Question to @Tim Jai.