# How to store changed form input in database in laravel 5.4

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I was trying to change a form input in laravel before validation I did manage to change input in listFormRequest.The is apparent when I use dd($data) in the listFormRequest and in my controller as well.
To be specific I used this[laravel 5.4 modify data before validation in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506302/laravel-5-4-modify-data-before-validation-in-request). But my problem is now I don't know how to save changed input to database.
My code in list form sample is

```
 public function rules()
{
      return [
        'title' =>'required',
        'description' =>'required',
        'url' =>'required',
        ];

}
  /**
 * Get data to be validated from the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function validationData()
  {
    $data = parent::validationData();
    if (is_string($url = array_get($data, 'url')))
    //dd($data);
    $query = 'amzsome=klwo';
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parsedUrl['query']);
    $url = 'https://'.$parsedUrl['host'] . $parsedUrl['path']. '?' .  $query;
    $data['url'] = $url;
    //dd($data);
    $this->replace($data);
     $data->create([ $request->input('url')]);
    //dd($data);
    return $data;

  }
```

To be specific, I am replacing query part of url with some query by assigning
new query to user submitted link.
dd($data) shows me changes clearly, when i try to execute the code but changed input doesn't get stored in database.
I have two options in my mind for changed input.(sorry this may change my question into more than one question).
1.First to save the replaced input into database(if second isn't possible).
2.Second (if possible) to save the original input as it is and create the new column for changed input and store it along with original input **without** creating a input field in form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The above code works fine. As I have mentioned already I can fetch changed request with dd($data). But the problem was I failed to inject request into database.
Posting answer in case someone else need help with the same.
Use

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->description = $request->description;
$post->url = $request->url;
$post->save();
```

instead of:

```
Post::create(request(['title','description','url']));
```

So my **question** now is
Why this behavior, what is the difference between the above codes.
I will post a new question if i have to(and if it is required).

Comment: Is it possible you need to add them to your fillable array? Laravel [prevents mass-assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) if you don't add the filenames into the `fillable` array in the mode.